# How to open a project in visual studio 2012, if it is written in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have installed vs2012 on my computer and I have to open a vs2010 project(the code  is written in windows form);
For example when I have to open "form.cs" I don`t see the windows form,when I need to open the code to debug,there is always a migration report..
I have read about how to open the project in different ways many times 
,but I need something specific how it can be open without problems!

Comment: I don't see any problems with opening an older version project with new versions of MVS, as it updates everything that needs to gets updated. I myself never had a problem with that.

Comment: Just open the `.sln` or the `.csproj` file. Am I missing something here?

Comment: close the migration report tab and open your form. And besides, the migration report opens in a web browser. then what's preventing you to open the form in Visual Studio?

Comment: When tried open with .sln,the response is:"To open it,please use a version

Comment: Then choose a version.

Comment: When i tried to open the ".sln" file the response is:"To open it use a version that supports this type of project"Ok..And trying to open ".csproj",when the migration report is closed,opening the "form.cs" the response is:The project does not exist in project directory.It may have been moved,renamed or deleted"!

Comment: try with some other project

Comment: it is the same for all projects.All of them has the statement "The project does not exist in project directory.It may have been moved,renamed or deleted"! I know that I haven`t deleted nothing.But I don`t understand why it is appearing//